# Protege-OWL: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, owl, protege

Im trying to run code use protege-owl. So I added the `protege.jar` and `protege-owl.jar` to library to import `edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.*`  and  `edu.stanford.smi.protege.*`.

I also added jena jar files to use in next steps.

First i wrote simple code to see how it works :

```
 import java.lang.Object;
 import edu.stanford.smi.protege.*;
 import edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.*;
 import edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.jena.JenaOWLModel;
 import edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.model.OWLNamedClass;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
           // TODO code application logic here
          JenaOWLModel model=ProtegeOWL.createJenaOWLModel();
          OWLNamedClass c= model.createOWLNamedClass("A");
          System.out.print(c.getName());   
       }
}
```

But it gives me this error :

```
CONFIG: Protege 3.0 Build 141, JVM 1.6.0_20-b02, memory=259M, Windows 7, encoding=UTF-8, language=fa, country=IR
WARNING: Look and feel not found: com.jgoodies.plaf.plastic.PlasticLookAndFeel -- SystemUtilities.loadLookAndFeel()
WARNING: Plugins directory not found: C:\Users\mona\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\plugins -- PluginUtilities.getPluginsDir()
WARNING: Exception Caught -- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/toedter/calendar/JDateChooser
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
        at edu.stanford.smi.protege.plugin.PluginUtilities.isLoadableClass(Unknown Source)
        at edu.stanford.smi.protege.plugin.PluginUtilities.checkPlugin(Unknown Source)
        at edu.stanford.smi.protege.plugin.PluginUtilities.checkPlugins(Unknown Source)
        at edu.stanford.smi.protege.plugin.PluginUtilities.processManifest(Unknown Source)
        at edu.stanford.smi.protege.plugin.PluginUtilities.loadPluginsWithClassLoader(Unknown Source)
        at edu.stanford.smi.protege.plugin.PluginUtilities.createClassLoaderAndLoadPlugins(Unknown Source)
        at edu.stanford.smi.protege.plugin.PluginUtilities.loadPlugins(Unknown Source)
        at edu.stanford.smi.protege.plugin.PluginUtilities.loadSystemPlugins(Unknown Source)
        at edu.stanford.smi.protege.plugin.PluginUtilities.loadPlugins(Unknown Source)
        at edu.stanford.smi.protege.plugin.PluginUtilities.init(Unknown Source)
        at edu.stanford.smi.protege.plugin.PluginUtilities.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at edu.stanford.smi.protege.util.SystemUtilities.init(Unknown Source)
        at edu.stanford.smi.protege.util.SystemUtilities.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at edu.stanford.smi.protege.model.Project.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.ProtegeOWL.createJenaOWLModel(ProtegeOWL.java:32)
        at javaapplication3.Main.main(Main.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) . . . .
```

What can I do ?

---

**Update:**
I replace protege.jar with protege-3.5.jar and now it gives :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: edu.stanford.smi.protege.model.SystemFrames.replaceFrame(Ledu/stanford/smi/protege/model/Frame;)V
        at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.model.impl.AbstractOWLModel.createSystemFrames(AbstractOWLModel.java:544)
        at edu.stanford.smi.protege.model.DefaultKnowledgeBase.<init>(DefaultKnowledgeBase.java:79)
        at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.model.impl.AbstractOWLModel.<init>(AbstractOWLModel.java:318)
        at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.jena.JenaOWLModel.<init>(JenaOWLModel.java:62)
        at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.jena.JenaKnowledgeBaseFactory.createKnowledgeBase(JenaKnowledgeBaseFactory.java:55)
        at edu.stanford.smi.protege.model.Project.createDomainKB(Project.java:429)
        at edu.stanford.smi.protege.model.Project.createDomainKnowledgeBase(Project.java:447)
        at edu.stanford.smi.protege.model.Project.<init>(Project.java:359)
        at edu.stanford.smi.protege.model.Project.<init>(Project.java:341)
        at edu.stanford.smi.protege.model.Project.createNewProject(Project.java:545)
        at edu.stanford.smi.protegex.owl.ProtegeOWL.createJenaOWLModel(ProtegeOWL.java:32)
        at javaapplication3.Main.main(Main.java:24)
Java Result: 1
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: When is this happening?  Are you trying to run Protege?  Trying to run your own Java code?   Protégé 3.x is also rather old;  unless you need something specific in it, you might want to use Protégé 4.x.

Comment: Since M D is using Protege classes that refer to Jena, I'm guessing he needs to use the classes from Protege 3.x - as far as I know, Protege 4.x does not use Jena any more. The errors shown make me think there are incompatible jars in the classpath. What I would do is download a Protege version, say 3.5., and make sure I have all and only the jars contained i that distribution in the classpath, minus the OSGi jars, which are not necessary for a standalone app.

Comment: I downloaded protege-owl.jar which is 3.24MB from different link and now it works.

Comment: @MD if it works, can you add it as an answer and accept it? That way, it's clearer which questions do not have answers and which ones do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded protege-owl.jar which is 3.24MB from different link and now it works.